# Can a Hydrogen Radical form in a chemical reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrolysis, hydrogen, radicals

Original question: During kolbe electrolysis of Formic acid, H2 is released at which electrode?

What I thought: H2 will form at cathode due to reduction of water. But will the Formic acid decompose to give H2 and CO2 by radical mechanism?

My doubt: Does H radical form in chemical reactions?

Comment: Yes a H radical form can form in chemical reactions. However it is extremely reactive and will exist for only a fleeting amount of time.

Comment: @MaxW  will there be release of H2 at the anode then?

Comment: @MaxW https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolbe_electrolysis

Comment: $\ce{HCOOH -> CO2 + H2}$

Comment: @MaxW That is the problem I am having. This is only possible if H radical forms in the reaction. I'm not sure if it will work as standard kolbe reaction.

Comment: If you get anything else how would it be a *Kolbe electrolysis*?

Comment: @MaxW What I mean is that will the reaction even happen? From the mechanism, first step is the formation of HCOO• after which it breaks down to give the products. I wanted to ask will it break down to give H• and those H• will combine to give H2 or will it procede some other way.

Comment: I understand the concerns that at the concurrent occuence of $\ce{H., HCOO-}$ at the anode,  the former would be first to oxidize.

Comment: @Poutnik I'm sorry but I am unable to understand what you mean.

Comment: Hehe, it may be mutual, as I cannot see what may be there not to understand... :-) I mean if formiate is oxidized at an anode to HCOO radical, and if by decarboxylation is created the atomary/radical hydrogen, it seems to me it may take priority in further onodic oxidation. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @Poutnik I think I shouldn't waste time on this as I am unable to find anything on the internet about kolbe electrolysis of formic acid. Looks like the question maker did not think through. (This is frequent in the material for the exam I'm preparing for)